# kafka-python: produce and consume messages from same topic at the same time by running concurrent process/scripts

Tags: python, apache-kafka, python-multiprocessing, kafka-python

Kafka set up locally:

```
bin/zookeeper-server-start.sh config/zookeeper.properties
bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties
```

and example test topic to store data is created:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic fortest --bootstrap-server localh
ost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1
```

Sample script is created to send example data and then read it from same test topic

```
import time
from kafka import KafkaProducer, KafkaConsumer
import multiprocessing

TOPIC = 'fortest'
producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'])

consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    TOPIC,
    bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
    auto_offset_reset='latest',
    group_id='my-consumer-1'
    )

def store_message():
    for _ in range(100):
        msg = b'message'
        producer.send(topic=TOPIC, value=msg)
        print(f'{msg} sent by Producer')
        time.sleep(3)

def get_processed_message():
    while True:
        messages = consumer.poll(timeout_ms=5000)

        if not messages:
             print('wait for messsages')
             time.sleep(5)
        else:
            print(f"Get messages: {messages.values()}")
```

It works in consecutive way like:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    store_message()
    get_processed_message()
```

But the question is - is it possible to run both functions in concurrent way, when producer is constantly sends and consumer is constantly reads messages using same topic at the same time? Tried to do this using multiprocessing:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    produce_initial_message = multiprocessing.Process(target=store_message)
    consume_processed_message = multiprocessing.Process(target=get_processed_message)
    produce_initial_message.start()
    consume_processed_message.start()
```

but only sending works, `consumer.poll()` never returns any value in this case and keep 'waiting' for messages. Same if move Consumer initialization and logic to the different `.py` script and run them both at the same time in different terminals
How this needs to be adjusted to work in such way?(Or this requires some more complicated logic/additional agents besides consumer and producer to handle?)

Comment: Try calling `producer.flush()` outside the for loop. Also, you really don't need it to sleep 3 seconds between each message

Comment: @OneCricketeer thanks for pointing out, indeed this one was missing. 3 seconds delay is added just for better workflow visualization

Answer (score 0):

Solved by:

1. Changing `store_message()` method to use infinite loop as well with using  `producer.flush()` after each sent message

```
def store_message():
    while True:
        msg = b'message'
        producer.send(topic=TOPIC, value=msg)
        print(f'{msg} sent by Producer')
        producer.flush()
        time.sleep(3)
```

2. Use threading for concurrent running instead of multiprocessing:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    t_producer = threading.Thread(target=store_message)
    t_consumer = threading.Thread(target=get_processed_message)
    t_producer.setDaemon(True)
    t_consumer.setDaemon(True)
    t_producer.start()
    t_consumer.start()
    while True:
        pass
```

Now it runs just as planned, thank you.

Comment: I'd suggest flushing less often than every message, by the way